# Sending SMS to mobile

Tags: authentication

In my academic project , i have done work regarding generating OTP and sending it to the my Gmail account, now i have been asked to send the generated OTP to mobile phone.

Is it possible to send the generated OTP as SMS to mobile phone number?(My location: Banglore INDIA)

I have used java code to generate OTP, (SMTP PORT 578) javaxmail.jar to deliver Mail, eclipse IDE and apache tomcat server 7 and MYSQL database of XAMPP. (OS:windows 7)

work done:I have created Database which holds username,password,email Id which are entered through registration page(html) , which is linked to database and through Login page which ask for username & password when entered it ask to generete OTP, The OTP is sent to mail(Gmail Id entered in Registration page).

Since i am a student and i am not Knowledgeable to query in right way, if there is any fault in my query , i apologize for it.

Please Can I get Positive Reply for my Query, Kindly help me regarding this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several different ways. There are companies who offer Web Services which will send SMS - so you could use a Java client to call one of these Web Services. You might have to pay for this though.

Another way would be to attach something like an Arduino to your PC, (over USB) and then add a GPRS shield to the Arduino. You could then write code on the arduino to wait for incoming data from the PC, and send the SMS.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Gerycon, i will follow with your response , can i get to know any one web service available in india and  is there any way that i can use my Dongle(with GSM Sim) connected to my PC (make integrate to project work tomcat server) to send sms to mobile phone

Comment: is there any link or video(youtube) which guide me with respect to your first option of your response

Comment: The link I showed you - http.twilio.com is to a company who do what you want. I ave never used them, I just googled for web-based SMS.